# Flatten a multilevel linked list through Collection framework

Tags: data-structures, java-8, java-stream

Consider this example http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flatten-a-linked-list-with-next-and-child-pointers/

I am able to flatten a multilevel linked list by collections in java but I am not able to establish relationship between a given node and its child node and next node . In the current example 10 has a child nodes with value 4,20 and 13 . I want to use Collections framework in a better way that can specify the child nodes and next nodes and then apply the flatten operation on given input. Please help me .

```
    List<List<Integer>> obj =new LinkedList<List<Integer>>();
    obj.add(Arrays.asList(10,5,12,7,11));
    obj.add(Arrays.asList(4,20,13,17,6));
    obj.add(Arrays.asList(2,16,9,8));
    obj.add(Arrays.asList(3,19,15));

    obj.stream().flatMap(e->e.stream()).forEach(i->System.out.print(i+" "));;
```

Comment: I got the output but I am not happy with the way I am storing the nodes . For example  I am not able to specify the child node of a given node .

Comment: You need a class for your nodes, as it is shown in the page you linked.

Comment: You are reversing the task. You don’t want to flatten a data structure, you want to create the structure out of a list of list. This is impossible. Using a `LinkedList` hasn’t anything to do with the “multilevel linked list” of that linked page. Your code has no semantic difference to, e.g. `List<List<Integer>> obj = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(10,5,12,7,11), Arrays.asList(4,20,13,17,6), Arrays.asList(2,16,9,8), Arrays.asList(3,19,15));`

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner  I created a class now can someone please help me to faltten the list http://ideone.com/tSGV1M

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem here is the code .

```
 import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Node {
    int data;
    List<Node> child;

    public Node(int data, List<Node> child) {
        this.data = data;
        this.child = child;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return data+" ";
    }
}

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
            List<Node> obj1 = new LinkedList<Node>();

        obj1.add(new Node(10, Arrays.asList(new Node(4,null),new Node(20,Arrays.asList(new Node(2, null))),
                new Node(13,Arrays.asList(new Node(16, Arrays.asList(new Node(3, null)))))  )));
        obj1.add(new Node(5, null));
        obj1.add(new Node(12,null));
        obj1.add(new Node(7,Arrays.asList(new Node(17, Arrays.asList(new Node(9, Arrays.asList(new Node(19, null),
                new Node(15, null))),new Node(8, null))
                ),new Node(6, null))
                ));
        obj1.add(new Node(11,null));

        int tail=obj1.size();

        for(int i=0;i<tail;i++)
        {
            Node n=obj1.get(i);
            if(n.child!=null)
            {
                for(Node o:n.child)
                {
                    obj1.add(tail, o);
                    tail++;
                }
                n.child=null;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(obj1);

    }
}
```